# Multiple Image in Canvas ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I want to show multiple image on a canvas.  I need to position them differently in the canvas. I made a class for my images :

```
class MapItem:Image
{
  public int DistanceToTop { get; set; }
  public int DistanceToLeft { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML looks like this :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Map:MapViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding All}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding DistanceToLeft}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding DistanceToTop}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

My ViewModel used as DataContext :

```
class MapViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<MapItem> All   { get; set; }

  public MapViewModel()
  {
    All = new ObservableCollection<MapItem>();
    var wSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ImagePath"));
    var wImage = new MapItem { Source = wSource, DistanceToLeft = 20, DistanceToTop = 20 };
    test = wImage;
    All.Add(wImage);
  }
}
```

Why in the XAML my binding to DistanceToLeft and DistanceToTop are not working ?!?
Isn't it suppose to automatically look in the object use in my ObservableCollection ?

**EDIT** : I still have my problem. But now I know it's related with the Binding.  I'm trying to implement all this using the MVVM pattern using the GalaSoft framework.  So to start I set my DataContext to my MapViewModel. Why can't I acces the properties of the MapItem from my ObservableCollection ?

**EDIT** : Finally with the help of Clemens and Rachel I ended up with this.

My MapItem Class:

```
class MapItem:Image
{
  public LatLon CoordMiddleOfImage { get; set; }
  public LatLon CoordTopLeftOfImage { get; set; }

  public int DistanceToTop
  {
    get { return (int) Canvas.GetTop(this); }
    set { Canvas.SetTop(this, value); }
  }

  public int DistanceToLeft
  {
    get { return (int)Canvas.GetLeft(this); }
    set { Canvas.SetLeft(this, value); }
  }

  public int ZOrder
  {
    get { return Panel.GetZIndex(this); }
    set { Panel.SetZIndex(this, value); }
  }
}
```

And my XAML like this :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding All}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas ClipToBounds="True"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

It works like a charm for now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite understand why after all you invented the `DistanceToLeft` and `DistanceToTop` properties and then struggle with binding. If you want to use Image controls as items, why not directly apply the attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`:

```
All = new ObservableCollection<Image>(); // no need for derived MapItem
var wSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ImagePath")); 
var wImage = new Image { Source = wSource }; 
Canvas.SetLeft(wImage, 20);
Canvas.SetTop(wImage, 20);
All.Add(wImage);
```

Hence, no need for a Style:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding All}">    
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>    
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>    
            <Canvas />    
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>    
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>    
</ItemsControl>
```

---

However, you should consider to create a real ViewModel class that is not a control, something like this:

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
}
```

Use it similar to your MapItem class

```
All = new ObservableCollection<ImageItem>();
ImageItem image = new ImageItem { Source = @"ImagePath", Left = 20, Top = 20 };
All.Add(image);
```

You would now define an ItemContainerStyle like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- ContentPresenter is the default item container in ItemsControl -->
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">                        
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I would like to integrate ZIndex to and a lot of other parameters to my object.  Your solution could work but utilmately the best would be to get my other attempt to work.  Thanks for your advice but I would really like to get the other way working.

Comment: I saw the edit.  I got it to work. When I run my app everything is working correctly.  But when I look at the XAML I still get errors on my bindings. But it is workin. Really weird ! Thanks alot !!!

Answer (score 1):

An `ItemsControl` wraps each item in a `ContentPresenter`, so the style in `ItemContainerStyle` is for the `ContentPresenter`, not the `Image`

If you remove `TargetType="Image"` from your style it should work fine

Comment: I already tried that and it still says "Cannot resolve property 'DistanceToLeft' in object of type 'Testing.Map.MapViewModel' wich is directly my dataContext.

If I put 20 as the value it works... So it's the binding that is causing the problem....

Comment: @KOTIX That error means it can't find the property on your class. Make sure it is a Property and not a Field (meaning it has `get`/`set` accessors), and that it is a public property on a public class.

Comment: As you can see in my class MapItem it is a property with a get/set but it is within my ObservableCollection. Is that a problem ? This property is set for each image I want to print from my Collection so I can't just put it in my viewModel...

Comment: @KOTIX I just noticed your error says it cannot resolve the property in object of type `MapViewModel`. Based on the code above, I had assumed you were binding your `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection<MapItem>`, so the binding should be referencing `MapItem.DistanceToLeft`, however the error you have posted is trying to find `MapViewModel.DistanceToLeft`. It looks like you need to double-check your bindings. I'd suggest using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for that.

Comment: I tried snoop but to be honest I don't know what I'm looking for in there... I can see what's my dataContext at each point in the tree and as soon as I enter the Canvas it's always my viewModel being my dataContext.  Should it be my MapItem at some point ?

Comment: @KOTIX Snoop should show you a `Canvas` with a bunch of of `<ContentPresenter>` objects as children, and the `DataContext` of each `ContentPresenter` should be of type `MapItem` because of your `ItemsSource` binding to the `All` property.

Comment: When I bind to the ObservableCollection "All" and it is a normal class, my contentpresenters' DataContext are good. As soon as All is a list of Image or a class derived from Image, my contentpresenters' DataContext are wrong. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: @KOTIX Its hard to tell without seeing your code, but you may have to use a `RelativeSource Self` binding since the item in the `ObservableCollection` is a `UI` element. Personally I would suggest not mixing UI elements with data elements at all. Instead make your `MapItem` a regular class with a Source string property in addition to your Top and Left properties, and making the `ItemTemplate` an `Image` that has the `Source` property bound to whatever the string in your `MapItem` is (you may need a `Converter` to convert the string to an `Image` depending on how your image string is stored)